# Is there some way to define getters/setters of a private property without having a second property to hold the value?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a public readonly property that calculates its value based upon a couple of other private variables. I read from the calculated property a lot. The variables that are used in the calculation change very rarely. I currently have the getter of the readonly perform the calculation logic, but it makes more sense to me to push the new value into the property when the dependant variables change.

An example of my current code:

```
public class rectangle()
{
    public rectangle(int height, int width)
    {
        _height = height;
        _width = width;
    }

    public void resize(int heightOffset, int widthOffset)
    {
        _height += heightOffset;
        _width += widthOffset;
    }

    private int _height;
    private int _width;
    public int area
    {
        get
        {
            return _height * _width;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is overly simplified, but does a good job of showing what I mean. _height and _width can change, but they rarely ever do. The area property is read from a lot... I'd estimate that the _height/_width change once for every 100,000+ reads of the area property.

Now, if it was just multiplication, I wouldn't be concerned... but the actual calcuations are complex and I'm seeing a lot of run time being sunk into repetitous superfluous calculations.

I know that I can do the following to fix it:

```
...

private int _height;
private int height
{
    set
    {
        _height = value;
        _area = _height * _width;
    }
}

private int _width;
private int width
{
    set
    {
        _width = value;
        _area = _height * _width;
    }
}

private int _area;
public int area
{
    get
    {
        return _area;
    }
}

...
```

The above code makes a lot more sense given my circumstances, but it just seems to me that there must be a better way to do this. I know that, given my first example, I could get rid of the properties and move the calculation logic to the resize() method... but in the real code it isn't just one method that affects the private values. I don't want to have to comb through my code to find every occurrence, and it doesn't seem maintainable to do so.

Is the second method the way to go? I know it works, but something about it feels wrong. I think my concern is that it seems odd to have a private property storing it's value into a private variable. I may be overthinking this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you know property accessors can have access modifiers?

For example:

```
public string A
{
    internal get
    {
        // Whatever
    }
    private set
    {
        // Whatever
    }
}
```

This works for auto-properties too:

```
public string A
{
    internal get;
    private set;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Ok, now you know about accessor access modifiers, what about this?

```
public class rectangle()
{
    public rectangle(int height, int width)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
    }

    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Area { get; private set; }

    public void resize(int heightOffset, int widthOffset)
    {
        Height += heightOffset;
        Width += widthOffset;

        RefreshArea();
    }

    private void RefreshArea() 
    {
        Area = Height * Width;
    }
}
```

*Goodbye, private fields!*

Comment: Yep, but that doesn't help... the setter still needs to store it's value somewhere, which implies a spearate private variable. My issue is that I have a private property for a private variable. It seems like overkill.

Comment: @Chronicide And what about storing it in the auto-property, auto-implemented underlying setter field?

Comment: Doesn't implementing the setter property preclude auto-properties? I can't go: public int height{set{height = value; area = height*width;}} as that is the perfect example of an infinite loop...

Comment: @Chronicide Obviously this isn't possible.

Comment: @Chronicide: how does accessing a property after setting it cause an infinite loop?

Comment: @Chronicide I've never tried doing so, but a property accessor, the setter, is a method (set_YourPropertyName()). If you call set_YourPropertyName(value), it'll call set_YourPropertyName and so on... :)

Comment: @Chronicide No problem! Hope it was useful for you

Comment: @Christopher Pfohl: The setter set's itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, which sets itself, whic

Comment: @Chronicide: sorry, totally misread your comment. Your example wouldn't compile because you are using Height's getter in your setter, but no getter is defined.  It confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested method will work, as long as you make sure that you always use the height/width properties to set _height and _width.

There's nothing wrong with using private properties for private variables.  It moves update code to a single location so that it's easier to maintain.

As Matías stated, you could make your height and width properties have accessors with different access modifiers, so that you could read, but not write to your height/width properties outside of this class.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you modify the private fields from many places in your code instead of always going through the property for those fields.  Best case scenario, you limit access to only call the properties and then you are assured you only have a couple places calling the recalculation.

But, if you can't or won't do that, then you are right, it would be a pain to make sure that every time you modified one of your private fields you would have to make sure you calculated your corresponding field.

You also said that performance is an issue and you would like to save on calling the calculation routine.

So, if you must retain access to the private fields, perhaps you could make your recalculation conditional on when those private fields actually do change. Like this:

```
private int _height; 
private int height 
{ 
    set 
    { 
        _height = value; 
    } 
} 

private int _width; 
private int width 
{ 
    set 
    { 
        _width = value; 
    } 
} 

private int _area; 
// have some variables to store the values used in the calculation
private int _areaWidth;
private int _areaHeight;
public int area 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        // only do the calculation if these values have changed
        if(_areaWidth != _width || _areaHeight != _height)
        {
            _areaWidth = _width;
            _areaHeight = _height;
            _area = _width * _height;
        }
        return _area; 
    } 
}
```

This way, you keep your calculation in one place, and you only recalculate when the values have changed.  Doing a conditional check is less expensive than whatever your calculation really is.

Answer (score 0):

A way that I normally do it is like this:

```
class Rectangle
{
    int _height;
    public int height { get { return _height; } set { _height = value; _area = null; }}

    int _width;
    public int width { get { return _width; } set { _width = value; _area = null; } }

    int? _area;
    public int area
    {
        get
        {
            if(!_area.HasValue)
                _area = _width * _height;
            return _area.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I will use traditional C# coding style (I.e.: caps for class names and public properties) for ease of reading. I recommend you do the same*

One way to fix your problem is to simply make the `Rectangle` class immutable and use `Lazy<T>` for the area to delay calculating your expensive thing:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    private readonly Lazy<int> _area;

    public Rectangle(int height, int width)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
        _area = new Lazy<int>(() => Height * Width);
    }

    public int Height { get; private set; }

    public int Width { get; private set; }

    public int Area
    {
        get
        {
            return _area.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The benefits of immutable classes/structs are countless.  The downside is that whenever you want to 'change' a `Rectangle` object you'd have to use `new` or a static member of `Rectangle` like:

```
...
public static Rectangle Widen(Rectangle rect, int widenByAmount)
{
    return new Rectangle(rect.Height, rect.Width + widenByAmount);
}
...
```

If you have LinqPad try the following:

```
void Main()
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(5, 10);
    r.Height.Dump();
    r.Width.Dump();
    r.Area.Dump();
    r.Area.Dump();
    r = Rectangle.Widen(r, 10);
    r.Area.Dump();
    r.Area.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Rectangle
{
    private readonly Lazy<int> _area;

    public Rectangle(int height, int width)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
        _area = new Lazy<int>(() =>
            {
                "Calculating...".Dump();
                return Height * Width;
            });
    }

    public int Height { get; private set; }

    public int Width { get; private set; }

    public int Area
    {
        get
        {
            return _area.Value;
        }
    }

    public static Rectangle Widen(Rectangle rect, int widenByAmount)
    {
        return new Rectangle(rect.Height, rect.Width + widenByAmount);
    }
}
```

For me it spits out:

```
5
10
Calculating...
50
50
Calculating...
100
100
```

Comment: Hey, but this will work once... second access to Area will update its value??

Comment: I think you mean `_area = new Lazy...`